# Metodologia e Documentação para Projetos ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, documentação, metodologia

Na empresa onde trabalho sempre tive total liberdade para desenvolver as aplicações solicitadas. Sempre trabalhei de forma singular apesar de ter um companheiro de trabalho pois, ambos desenvolvíamos projetos separados.

A partir da próxima semana, estarei trabalhando com dois auxiliares e estou pensando em aplicar alguma metodologia para desenvolvermos em pequena equipe e além disso, documentarmos toda as aplicações, algo que não acontece hoje em dia.

Atualmente trabalho com Asp.Net MVC 4 e C#. Qual seria a metodologia de desenvolvimento / documentação a qual mais se adequaria a esse meu modelo sendo que, pretendo documentar os projetos antigos?

É interessante destrinchar as camadas da aplicação em MVC e atribuir cada a um colaborador da equipe? Não vejo isso como uma solução muito prática, mas como disse, não tenho experiencia em desenvolvimento em equipe.

Apesar de soar como uma pergunta de opinião com diversas respostas, a minha intenção é receber uma indicação de um bom caminho a seguir para aplicar a melhor prática possível nessa minha nova situação.

Comment: De fato é um pergunta cujas respostas não podem ser embasadas sem uma longa discussão. Uma discussão bem bacana, só não creio que seja válida para o formato do SO.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%C3%ADtulo Procure achar um título que explique em uma frase curta o seu problema, onde você quer chegar. Evite títulos muito genéricos.

Comment: Opinião: **a)** só crie os documentos que estão fazendo falta e se tiver uma clara indicação de como eles irão ajudar daqui pra frente (por exemplo, um documento que explica como configurar o ambiente de desenvolvimento pode ser útil e o novo membro do time pode criá-lo). **b)** Invista mais no design e no código em si do que em documentos que os expliquem. **c)** Não divida tarefas por camadas mas sim por recursos/features/requisitos "end-to-end". **d)** Não divida tarefas, cada um tem que desenvolver a habilidade de trabalhar na próxima prioridade da lista.

Comment: Não há nenhuma menção na pergunta sobre *revision control*... Já há votos para fechar como "baseada em opiniões", não seria o caso de dar mais contexto da situação-em-questão em relação ao workflow-do-software-atual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou responder uma parte da sua pergunta.

#### É interessante destrinchar as camadas da aplicação em MVC e atribuir cada a um colaborador da equipe? Não vejo isso como uma solução muito prática, mas como disse, não tenho experiencia em desenvolvimento em equipe.

Não. Destrinchar as camadas causa um complicador para a configuração (pacotes, `Web.config`, e assim por diante), além do que a IDE não funciona muito bem com essa separação de camadas. Por exemplo, se você usa o pacote [DotNetOpenAuth Entensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet/), a IDE se perde e marca erros que não existem se a configuração não for estritamente correta.

#### Atualmente trabalho com Asp.Net MVC 4 e C#. Qual seria a metodologia de desenvolvimento / documentação a qual mais se adequaria a esse meu modelo sendo que, pretendo documentar os projetos antigos?

Depende do modelo de trabalho atual. Há algumas metodologias de desenvolvimento que você pode utilizar:

- Scrum
- Agile
- Extreme Programming

Já para a documentação você pode utilizar o [recurso de comentários padronizados do .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx).